# Spring MVC, send data to MySQL with IF statement

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm making an online shop, and... could somebody tell me why this code doesn't work?

If I write SQL statement without IF then it works fine, but I have to check which phone I chose.

PhoneController:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/cart.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView addToCart(@RequestParam String selectedPhone, Phone phone, DBConnection db) throws ClassNotFoundException{

    String selectiPhone = "?selectedPhone=Phone1";

    if (selectedPhone.equals(selectiPhone))
    {
        db.Query("INSERT INTO `onlineshop`.`cart` (`name`, `company`, `type`, `price`) VALUES ('"
                        + phone.getName1() + "', '"+phone.getCompany1()+"', '" + phone.getType() + "', '"
                        + phone.getPrice1() +"')");
    }

    ModelAndView cart = new ModelAndView("Cart");
    return cart;    

}
```

fragment of Phone1.jsp:

```
<form action="/OnlineShop/cart.html?selectedPhone=Phone1" method="post">
<div style="padding-right: 40px">
     <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedPhone` will contain "Phone1" only, not the ? and the parameter name as well.

```
  if ("Phone1".equals(selectedPhone)) {
```

Should work better for you.

Good luck.

But I've no idea how and if the Values for Phone and DBConnection will make it into your method...